# unable to apply CSS to control on page

Tags: css

I have a following `.aspx` page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Control</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        input[type="radio"][checked]  +label 
         {
             font-weight: bold; 
             color: Green;
         }
         input[type="radio"][disabled] +label 
         {
             font-weight: bold; 
             color: Green;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="val1" disabled="disabled"/>val1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="val2"/>val2
    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="val3"/>val3

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?
because the css styles that I defined in the  tag are not getting implied on the page.
Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mK66C/)  for the said sample

As per the code the disabled button should be of green color but it is not.. 
similarly for the checked one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put radio button text in label

```
<input type="radio" id="val1" name="abc" value="val1" disabled="disabled"/>
<label for="val1">val1</label>
```

And then you can use your css selectors

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label
{
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: Green;
}
input[type="radio"]:disabled+label
{
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: Green;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't declared labels for the radio buttons...Do this.

```
<input id="abc1" type="radio" name="abc" value="val1" disabled="disabled"/><label for="abc1">val1</label><br/>
<input id="abc2" type="radio" name="abc" value="val2" checked="checked"/><label for="abc2">val2</label>
```

Comment: This works but if I check the other radio button then it does not change the color of selected one..